# How to compile C code and run the compile code with Pexpect?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, pexpect

I have C code and I want to compile and then run it with pexpect. How can I do it?? but this command is not working.

```
child = pexpect.spawn("gcc -o pwn code.c)
```

Comment: Can you compile the C code first, and then run it from python?

Comment: In [1]: import pexpect    
In [12]: pexpect.spawn("gcc ab.c")                                                                                                                    
Out[12]: <pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn at 0x7efcf4787130>
In [13]: pexpect.spawn("./a.out")                                                                                                                     
Out[13]: <pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn at 0x7efcf432d8e0>

In [14]: pexpect.spawn("./a.out").read()                                           
Out[14]: b'Hello world'

Comment: @QuantumMecha sir I have to try it with `Pexpect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the command, you may have to move the pexpect cursor forward  by adding a `child.expect_exact()` after the `pexpect.spawn`:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 using Python 3.8

```
import sys

import pexpect

print("Method 1:")
child = pexpect.spawn("gcc -o pwn code.c")
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect_exact(["$", pexpect.EOF, ])
child = pexpect.spawn("./pwn")
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect_exact(["$", pexpect.EOF, ])
```

**Output:**

```
Method 1:
Hello, world!
```

However, instead of spawning two children, you may want to try these alternatives; in your case, since you do not need to keep a child process open, I recommend Method 3, using `pexpect.run`:

```
import sys

import pexpect

print("Method 2:")
child = pexpect.spawn("bash")
# Shows all output
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect_exact("$")
child.sendline("gcc -o pwn2 code.c")
child.expect_exact("$")
child.sendline("./pwn2")
child.expect_exact("$")
child.close()

print("Method 3:")
list_of_commands = ["gcc -o pwn3 code.c",
                    "./pwn3", ]
for c in list_of_commands:
    command_output, exitstatus = pexpect.run(c, withexitstatus=True)
    if exitstatus != 0:
        print("Houston, we've had a problem.")
    print(command_output.decode().strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Method 2:
$ gcc -o pwn2 code.c
$ ./pwn2
Hello, world!
$
Method 3:

Hello, world!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

By using this way you can see your output

```
In [1]: import pexpect    
In [12]: pexpect.spawn("gcc ab.c")                                                                                                                    
Out[12]: <pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn at 0x7efcf4787130>
In [13]: pexpect.spawn("./a.out")                                                                                                                     
Out[13]: <pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn at 0x7efcf432d8e0>

In [14]: pexpect.spawn("./a.out").read()                                           
Out[14]: b'Hello world'
```

Comment: on my system, it is not compiling the c code

Comment: the code executes without any error but the code is not compiled

Comment: which os you are using?
can I see the the path and code you are doing?

I am using ubuntu, It is working in my system with proof I have sent the code.

Comment: thank you sir it worked